# How to use upstart on VirtualBox guest

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, upstart

I have a custom upstart job with this basic structure:

```
description "ulfs_bar_example"
author "Ulf"

# Only run at runlevel 2 (Default multiuser)
start on runlevel 2
stop on runlevel [!2]

# Keep it alive
respawn

chdir /storage/_foo/bar
exec sudo -u the_user /storage/_foo/venv/bin/python /storage/_foo/bar/the_app.py
```

This is run on a `Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS` instance in `VirtualBox 5.0.26`.

`/storage/_foo/` exists in the guest disk

`bar/` exists in the host system (also `Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS`) and is mounted through [Guest Additions](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html) and some symlinking at `/storage/_foo/`

```
$ cd /storage/_foo
$ ls -alF
...
lrwxrwxrwx  1 the_user code   43 aug 18 14:23 bar -> /mnt/bar_at_host
...
```

The job can be started without any problems after the guest is booted like this:

```
$ sudo start ulfs_bar_example
```

But as stated in the conf-file I whant the job to start when runlevel 2 is entered at normal booting. But there seems to be some issue with mounting since the job won't get started. In `dmesg` I get this:

```
[    8.793493] init: Failed to spawn ulfs_bar_example main process: unable to change working directory: No such file or directory
```

Without any success I have tried changing:

```
start on runlevel 2
```

to various things similar to this:

```
start on (local-filesystems and runlevel 2)
```

**What am I doing wrong? How can I fix this?**

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that your system is entering runlevel 2 and not another runlevel? Have you tried `start on runlevel [2345]`?

Comment: At some point it definitely enters runlevel 2: `$ runlevel` will return `N 2`. Adding `[2345]` to `start on` gives me the same error in `dmesg`.